# Data to be inserted into MySQL via user input using Windows 7

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a website to take up user data and also add this user data to pre defined data which I have it before hand added to mysql. Please can somebody suggest me how can I do it or give me some head start in a direction. I am using a Windows 7 machine. I am a complete newbie and trying to learn so please correct me. Thank you.

Comment: if it is a website, your OS does not matter. Just create an input field with the datas and then insert them via php in your database.

Comment: Please can you post some good link to the tutorial with basic concepts

Comment: https://www.google.com/?q=php+mysql+tutorial